# What are various reasons why UIView.animate() would fail to animate a view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why my view won't animate, so I figured maybe it's because of some weird reason that I don't know about. Does anyone have any ideas on less common ways why `UIView.animate()` would fail to animate properly? The method I am using to animate my view is:

```
func animateView() {
    print("1")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.viewToAnimate.alpha = 0.0
        print("2")
    }, completion: {_ in
        print("3")
    })
}
```

What's even stranger (in my opinion), is that when I run, the console outputs

```
1
2
3
```

immediately, and does not take into consideration the delay of 2.0 seconds or the duration of 5.0 seconds... It appears my "animation" is instantaneous, making my view disappear immediately with an alpha of 0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], i.e. give us the list of steps to take to reproduce the issue, starting from "create a new project in Xcode".

Comment: @Sweeper The problem is, my project isn't small and I don't really know what to include (since I have no idea where the failure might be). I can't seem to replicate the failure.. That's why I was asking for generic ideas that people could suggest...common pitfall areas.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow can't really help you with that. Learn to isolate the problem using divide and conquer.

Comment: I guess I'll do my best... I'm guessing there aren't any weird reasons it wouldn't work?

Comment: There are too many possible reasons that it wouldn't work, all of which are due to code that you did not show. The code you have shown, if used correctly, does show an animation. Your question is analogous to asking "I used `print("Hello World")` but it isn't printing anything. What are the common reasons that would cause `print` to not work?".

Comment: Okay good point. Well I guess I'm kinda screwed, so I'll just keep "dividing and conquering". It is strange that the animate method zips through without taking into account the duration and delay.

Comment: Even though the animation has a delay and a duration, the actual value of `self.viewToAnimate.alpha` is changed the moment you call animate, not the other way around.  Have you tried using `UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator`?

Comment: @DPrice okay that makes sense. And I just tried `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, and exact same thing. The animation and then completion happens immediately, even with a 2 second duration and 2 second delay. Weird!

Comment: @Eric - are you certain no other piece of code has already set the `.alpha` property to zero? Change your first print line to: `print("1 - current alpha:", self.viewToAnimate.alpha)` to confirm. If it is *already* zero, that will result in **no** delay or duration.

Comment: @DonMag yes I'm sure. Also that would not explain the fact that the delay is not being taken into consideration.

Comment: @Eric - did you change your `print()` statement to confirm? As I said, if the target property to animate - `.alpha` in this case - is already equal (that is, is already 0), both the duration ***and*** the delay will be ignored. Another point: if somewhere in your code prior to calling your `animateView()` func has `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`, then again, no delay or duration. You really need to work backwards in your code and figure out what's going on before this executes.

Comment: I did. The alpha was not already 0. But thank you for pointing out that that would result in zero delay and duration! Good to know.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. I think there may be a bug. In my case, what I wanted to animate was the background color, which documentation states is animatable. I resolved the issue by also changing the frame, adding 0.01 to the width. Then the animation worked.

Comment: I note: "Apple discourages using these methods. Use the UIViewPropertyAnimator class to perform animations instead." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the reasons that I can think of:

1- You can check your device settings General-> Accessibility-> Vision-> Reduce Motion

2- You can check if anywhere in the code you call `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622420-setanimationsenabled

3- Try to call layoutIfNeeded on the view before calling the animation on the view. This has to do with how animations work, it needs initial state and end state and then it projects the difference between both states on a time graph. https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/

4- You are not calling the method on the main thread which can make it ask weird. Try to call it in a dispatch_main block

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's weird because a different animation later on works correctly. Also, does #3 apply if I'm using UIView.animate, or just CABasicAnimation?

Comment: All animations on iOS are run using Core Animation. UIKit's block-based animation methods are simply a convenience feature.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since it was the most helpful--thank you! Unfortunately I'm banned from asking any more questions because apparently my questions don't get enough positive votes :/